# Table with a break in dates and two 31-dec-4712

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `tab_assignment_xx`

```
date_from   date_end     action  person_number
01-Apr-2014 31-Jul-2014   HIRE   050498
01-Aug-2014 31-Jan-2015   OTHERS    050498
01-Feb-2015 30-Jun-2015   OTHERS    050498
01-Jul-2015 15-Nov-2015   OTHERS    050498
16-Nov-2015 **31-Dec-4712** OTHERS  050498
01-Jan-2016 **31-Dec-4712** OTHERS  050498
```

now in this record for employee 050498 there are two dates with 31-dec-12 and a break in the dates. For example before 01-Jan-16 it should have been 31-dec-2015 and not 31-dec-12.

i want to find such breaks in the entire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no Oracle at hand right now but this should do the job:

Finds all rows which have no "following" row but excludes the last row which of course does not have a following rows (thats why it's the last ;))

```
select *
  from tab_assignment_xx a 
 where not exists (select 1
                     from tab_assignment_xx b
                    where a.date_end + 1  = b.date_from
                      and a.person_number = b.person_number)
   and a.date_from != (select max(date_from)
                         from tab_assignment_xx c
                        where a.person_number = c.person_number);
```

Maybe you need to add TRUNC() to your dates - depends on the type of your columns to ignore times.

Found row:

```
+------------+------------+
| date_from  | date_end   |
+------------+------------+
| 2015-11-16 | 4712-12-31 |
+------------+------------+
```